# Bulk Insert into SQL Table with unique ID column that is not Identity

Tags: sql-server, merge

I wrote a procedure that use `MERGE` to insert/update data in a table, but here is my problem. The `ID` column on the table that is also the primary key column is NOT an `IDENTITY` column. I found a way to insert the data, but the potential is there to create gaps in the PK that I don't want.

Here is my code that currently works.

```
MERGE Table p 
USING (SELECT i.Col1, 
              i.Col2, 
              i.Col3, 
              (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID), 0) FROM Table1 i) +
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) ID
      ) a(Col1, Col2, Col3, ID)
ON p.Col1 = a.Col1
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE set p.Col2 = a.Col2, p.Col3 = a.Col3
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES (a.ID, a.Col1, a.Col2, a.Col3)
```

The `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)` will give me unique values, but if 10 of the 20 records gets updated, it will create gaps in my ID column on the other inserts.

I've tried

```
(Select ISNULL(MAX(ID), 0) + 1 from Table)
```

but obviously this will only work correctly if there is only 1 record to be inserted. The bulk operation doesn't execute the sub-query for each insert statement, and that causes an PK violation.

I can't change the `ID` column to be an `identity` column as a legacy application still inserts information into that table, and will fail if I change it to an identity column.

Can anybody give me another way of doing the Merge without having to iterate through the whole table a execute each update/insert separately?

Comment: `IDENTITY` fields have gaps too. This isn't an issue you should be concerned by.

Comment: This query can't work, the aliases `s` and `i` do not map to a table

Comment: My Mistake, I actually have a join on the original query. I've edited the question

Comment: @OGHaza the problem is that they can merge from a table (Table1 in the example) that have 10k + records, and it can potentially create gaps of 10k between two ID's

Comment: @Jaques,it can work.first get max before merge.then somehow use this Max variable value inside using to increment by one.though i am trying myself.any problem ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh that is what I'm doing in the USING part of the merge, and that works, but if you merge 10,000 records and 9,999 gets updated and 1 inserted, a gap of 9,999 will be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy solution is to merge in two steps.  During the first step, update existing rows.  During the second step, insert new rows.  That avoids the gap problem because the second step does inserts only.

Comment: How do you exclude the existing columns then in the insert part. Add a `where Col1 not in (Select Col1 from Table)`?

Comment: Just omit `when not matched then insert` from the first query, and omit `when matched then update` from the second

Comment: It doesn't work. The ID jumps from 10729 to 21459 when it inserts 1 and updates the rest. Total Rec count is 10729 in.

Comment: Right, I guess you do need a `where not exists` subquery then.  Would you like an example of that?

Answer (score 0):

suppose ,

```
Declare @Max int
select @max=isnull(id,0) from table2

now inside using,

      select * ,@Max +ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select 0))
      from Table2
```

got it ?

Comment: This is exactly what happens in my current `USING`. It will still create gaps if there are updates